# Post Request to API not working | Angular 10.2

Tags: angular, api, post, httprequest

I'm trying to create a new Guest in my DB over a API I made myself. The API works fine with a C#-Front-end and Postman. Now I'm trying to use Angular for my front-end. I'm very new to Angular.

This is my Post-httpsRequest. Did a make a obvious mistake? I can't figure it out why it's not working. No Error appears in the console or Log in Browser.

```
save(guest: Guest) {

return this.http.post<Guest>(this.REST_URL, guest)
  .pipe(
    retry(3),
    catchError(this.handleError)
   ); 
}
```

Comment: This will return a Observable, you need to subscribe it to do http post request.

Comment: return this.http.post<Guest>(this.REST_URL, guest).pipe(retry(3),catchError(this.handleError)).subscribe(guest => { return guest });
Like this? the compiler ask for a unsubscription

Comment: Observables are lazy. They're not doing anything until you subscribe to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably works but you don't use the result properly. Check in the network tab of your browser if the request is done.
You can change your code like that:

```
save(guest: Guest): Observable<Guest> { //Adding the return type

return this.http.post<Guest>(this.REST_URL, guest)
  .pipe(
    retry(3),
    catchError(this.handleError)
   ); 
}
```

And then usage will be:

```
save(guest).subscribe( resultGuest => {
 // Process the result here
  }
);
```

Read here https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular
This is due to the async result of the post request